# Add animated overlay to video from camera

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I need to overlay multiple images with animated position, alpha and rotation on recorded video. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Currently I'm looking at ffmpeg, is it possible to add position animation to overlays using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=mod((1080/4 + sin(t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(t*300\,1080)[res];" -map "[res]" -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

## Explanation:

Overlay input [1] (overlay.png) over input [0] (video.mp4) and position overlay using evaluation x=mod((1080/4 + sin(t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(t*300\,1080), where t = time in milliseconds. Then map overlay result to stream [res], and output to out.mp4.

A more complex example with multiple overlays and using gif as overlay:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i overlay.gif -filter_complex `
>> "[0][1]overlay=x=mod((1080/4 + sin(t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(t*300\,1080):shortest=1[res];`
>> [res][1]overlay=x=mod((200*1 + 1080/4 - sin(2*t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(100 + t*300\,1080):shortest=1[res];`
>> [res][1]overlay=x=mod((200*2 + 1080/4 - sin(-90 + t/2)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(150 + t*250\,1080):shortest=1[res];`
>> [res][1]overlay=x=mod((200*3 + 1080/4 - sin(90 + 3*t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(200 + t*100\,1080):shortest=1[res];`
>> [res][1]overlay=x=mod((200*4 + 1080/4 - sin(180 + t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(t*250\,1080):shortest=1[res];`
>> [res][1]overlay=x=mod((200*5 + 1080/4 - sin(-180 + t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=mod(t*100\,1080):shortest=1[res];`
>> [res][1]overlay=x=mod((200*6 + 1080/4 - sin(2*t)*1080/4)\,1920):y=100 + mod(100 + t*300\,1080):shortest=1[res]`
>> " -map "[res]" -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```